# Get Permissions with client object model

Tags: document-library, permissions, javascript, client-object-model, security

i want to add a permission on a folder who's inside a document library with javascript/jquery/client object model.

The problem i have is, its a custom permission level created when some feature is deployed. I need to get a reference of it and assign it to a folder.